# Dynamic Stack : Java

Tags: java, stack

Can anyone explain, why does the value of **'tos'** variable change as diplayed in the stacktrace?

Following is the code for DynamicStack.java:

```
public class DynamicStack{
private int stck[];
int tos;

DynamicStack(int size){
    stck = new int[size];
    tos = -1;
}

                   // Following push method implements growable stack.
public void push(int item){
    if(tos == stck.length-1){
        int temp[] = new int[2*stck.length];    
        for(int i=0; i < stck.length; i++) temp[i] = stck[i];
        stck = temp;
        stck[++tos] = item;
    }

    else
        stck[++tos] = item;
}


public int pop(){
    if(tos < 0) {
        System.out.println("Stack underflow");
        return 0;
    } else return stck[tos--];
}}
```

Following is the code for Test_Dynamic_Stack.java:

```
public class Test_Dynamic_Stack{
public static void main(String a[]){
    DynamicStack mystack1 = new DynamicStack(5);
    DynamicStack mystack2 = new DynamicStack(8);

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) mystack1.push(i);
    for(int i=10;i<20;i++) mystack2.push(i);

    System.out.println("In mystack1");
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        System.out.println("Mystack1: "+mystack1.pop());
        System.out.println("Mystack2: tos = "+mystack1.tos);
    }

    System.out.println("In mystack2");
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Mystack2: "+mystack2.pop());
        System.out.println("Mystack2: tos = "+mystack2.tos);
    }
}
}
```

Following is the stacktrace:

`In mystack1
Mystack1: 6
Mystack2: tos = 5
Mystack1: 5
Mystack2: tos = 4
Mystack1: 4
Mystack2: tos = 3
Mystack1: 3
Mystack2: tos = 2
Mystack1: 2
Mystack2: tos = 1
Mystack1: 1
Mystack2: tos = 0
Mystack1: 0
Mystack2: tos = -1
In mystack2
Mystack2: 19
Mystack2: tos = 8
Mystack2: 18
Mystack2: tos = 7
Mystack2: 17
Mystack2: tos = 6
Mystack2: 16
Mystack2: tos = 5
Mystack2: 15
Mystack2: tos = 4
Mystack2: 14
Mystack2: tos = 3
Mystack2: 13
Mystack2: tos = 2
Mystack2: 12
Mystack2: tos = 1
Mystack2: 11
Mystack2: tos = 0
Mystack2: 10
Mystack2: tos = -1`

Finally, got the output.. :)

Comment: In `mystack1` section, your logging `mystack2 tos` every time not `mystack1 tos`. Is that intended?

Comment: You're pushing 2 elements on the stack 2 and trying to pop 12 after. I don't get your question. Are you confused about the output cause of your typos? Fix those and re-run your code.

Comment: It's 10 in your code not 0. When you are pushing to mstack2

Comment: Line 10 of your Test_Dynamic_Stack test class: System.out.println("Mystack2: tos = " + mystack2.tos); should be System.out.println("Mystack2: tos = " + mystack1.tos);

Comment: Sorry, for the typo!.. Thanks, @OlivierMeurice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

`for(int i=10;i<20;i++) mystack2.push(i);` to `for(int i=0;i<20;i++) mystack2.push(i);`

In your code you pushed just ten elements.